# Not able to add cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Tags: node.js, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, cordova-plugin-file

I am trying to install cordova-plugin-file-transfer for photo capture upload but i am getting below error.

```
E:\projects\XYZ>phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
Installing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" for android


Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-file-transfer': CordovaError: Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-file@>=5.0.0". Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency.
    at C:\Users\nagarajupendota\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:544:43
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-file@>=5.0.0". Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency.
```

I am trying since two days please help to solve me issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-file
2. phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
3. if 2. dont work use phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer  --force after 1.

Comment: i tried point number three also not working. @Artem Aksentenko

Comment: install phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-file first, you have cordova-plugin-file@>=4.3.3 but you need cordova-plugin-file@>=5.0.0

Comment: First have to remove file plugin and then add it again to get  latest, just reinstalling usually doesn’t get the latest